# How to interpret this simple periodic function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have been given the function f(x) = x between $\pi$/3 and $\pi$/2, and f(x) = $0$ after $\pi$/2 up to 2$\pi$ and from $0$ to $\pi/3$. Which graph interprets this function correctly? I personally believe its the first because there is nothing to suggest to me that it should be $0$ at $\pi$, but I am never sure with these questions.

[Image is linked here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMHUz.jpg)
thanks for the help!

Comment: You have zero chance of being answered. There are too many students doing assessments at the moment. What are your own thoughts and why, that might get a response.

Comment: You took the time to answer though, so why couldn't you have shared your thoughts on the question, instead of telling me I won't get an answer to the question?

Comment: I was trying to help you not to waste your time and also suggested how you might get a response. You still have not tried that though.

Comment: I've added an extra sentence expressing my personal beliefs. Can you do the same now please? :)

Comment: It says the function is 0 between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: Any other great insights you'd like to add?

Comment: If the function is 0 between those two values and $\pi$ is between those two values what is the value of f at $\pi$? Another insight I would like to add is that you are relentlessy rude.